# Print All data in a grid-IE issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am working on the print functionality in asp.net and I am using the below code for the print.

```
 GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")
        .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
    sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
    sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=1');");
    sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
    sb.Append(gridHTML); 
    sb.Append("\");");
    sb.Append("printWin.document.close();"); 
    sb.Append("printWin.focus();"); 
    sb.Append("printWin.print();"); 
    sb.Append("printWin.close();};"); 
    sb.Append("</script>");  
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString()); 
    GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Above code print all the data grid contents. It works good in IE. Print options are coming inside the new window. But in IE , print property page is coming in the separate window. How can I fix this for IE?
New window attached with the print property pages of the chrome. But in IE , Window and property pages are separate.
I am attaching screen shot for both IE and Chrome.
[image: Chrome]
[image: 2]

Comment: Do you want to fix the browser :) ? Every browser has it's own behavior and setting.

Comment: You want the Print Property window to show on the same window in IE, like it does in Chrome?  That's an application difference, and is not something you can control with your application.  It's how IE and Chrome choose to do printing...